# Overloading assignment operator for Stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack, overloading, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the assignment operator for my Stack class (in C++). When I run my output, I get the following:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
(empty)
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!

The first line represents Stack a, the second line represents Stack b (see main()) and the "Freeing memory!" is the destructor. For whatever reason Stack a's contents are not copying into Stack b's contents. I have verified that the capacity space is there (did a bunch of print statements) but the copying is not happening. Can someone help?

Here is my Stack constructor, copy constructor, and destructor:

```
/********************************/
Stack::Stack()
{
    top = -1; // array counter starts at 0
    stk = new int[MAXSIZE];
    capacity = MAXSIZE;
}
/********************************/

/********copy constructor ***********/
Stack::Stack(const Stack& source) {
  stk = new int[source.capacity]; // allocates new array space for the copy constructor
   for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
      stk[i] = source.stk[i];
    }
    top = source.top;
    capacity = source.capacity;
} /******* end copy constructor *******/

Stack::~Stack() {
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete[] stk;
}


Here is my main:


int main() {

    Stack a;
    for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        a.push(i);
    }
    //cout << "\n Using copying incorrectly...\n";
    //Stack b(a);
    Stack b;
    b = a;
    a.display();
    b.display();
```

Comment: Did you overload the assignment operator? Can you show that part it if so?

Answer (score 0):

`b=a` is invoking the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. Your supplied code example doesn't include an assignment operator, `operator=()`. Your assignment operator should include essentially the same logic as your copy constructor so you'd be best to move that logic to a new function and have both the copy constructor and assignment operator call this new function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

1. If you want to fall into copy constructor you need to use your commented code not assignment (`Stack b(a)`), because, if you use `b = a`, compiler will call the operator= and you will get memory leak error as it does not apply deep copy on your pointer `stk` but it wants to delete the pointer and deallocate the memory in the destructor, i.e. it does not allocate memory for your pointer. If you want to use `=` you have to assign it in the same line as you are creating your object: `Stack b = a`. This is equivalent to `Stack b(a)`.
2. Also, you need to use your `source.top` in the loop. You might want to do it by leaving `top = source.top;` before your loop.

Also, make sure, if you have any value on the `top` index of your stack or if it is pointing to an empty spot in your stack. Based on that you need to decide if you need to leave `=` sign in your for loop in your copy constructor or not.

I hope it helps.